# How to convert a string to number in PL/SQL

Tags: database, string, plsql, numbers

I have 5 character string which can have numbers, decimal points, alphabets and spaces. I wanted to convert this string to a number (integer) if all the characters in string are numbers. i.e.

- No decimal points allowed
- No +/- sign allowed
- Spaces are not allowed in between but they can be allowed at extremes

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20):

Use [To_Number Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_number.php) in PL/SQL to convert a string into number, see below for example.

```
to_number('1210.73', '9999.99') would return the number 1210.73 
to_number('546', '999') would return the number 546 
to_number('23', '99') would return the number 23
```

EDIT:

In PL/SQL you can check whether a string consists of numeric characters or not by using [LENGTH](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/length.php), [TRIM](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php) and [TRANSLATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php) functions.

```
LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(string1, ' +-.0123456789', ' ')))
```

Comment: What if there are alphabets, decimal points in string and I want to convert it to Integer ONLY IF numbers are present in the string.

Answer (score 4):

`to_number` function converts a string to a number.

Comment: How to check for validity of string for conditions mentioned above?

Comment: use the Instr Functions to check if non valid chars are in the string before converting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function is_int(p_str in varchar2) return number as
begin
  if regexp_instr(p_str, '^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]{1,5}[[:space:]]*$') > 0 then
    return 1;
  end if;

  return 0;
end;
/
show errors

with strings as (
  select '12345' as string from dual
  union all
  select '1234' as string from dual
  union all
  select '123' as string from dual
  union all
  select '12' as string from dual
  union all
  select '1' as string from dual
  union all
  select '01' as string from dual
  union all
  select '' as string from dual
  union all
  select '  345' as string from dual
  union all
  select '123  ' as string from dual
  union all
  select '12.45' as string from dual
  union all
  select '12 45' as string from dual
  union all
  select '12,45' as string from dual
  union all
  select '-1234' as string from dual
  union all
  select '+1234' as string from dual
  union all
  select 'A2345' as string from dual
)
select testcase, to_number(string)
from strings
where is_int(string) = 1
;

  TESTCASE TO_NUMBER(STRING)
---------- -----------------
         1             12345
         2              1234
         3               123
         4                12
         5                 1
         6                 1
         8               345
         9               123

8 rows selected.

create or replace function to_int(p_str in varchar2) return number as
begin
  if regexp_instr(p_str, '^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]{1,5}[[:space:]]*$') > 0 then
    return to_number(p_str);
  end if;

  return null;
end;
/
show errors

with strings as (
  select 1 as testcase, '12345' as string from dual
  union all
  select 2, '1234' as string from dual
  union all
  select 3, '123' as string from dual
  union all
  select 4, '12' as string from dual
  union all
  select 5, '1' as string from dual
  union all
  select 6, '01' as string from dual
  union all
  select 7, '' as string from dual
  union all
  select 8, '  345' as string from dual
  union all
  select 9, '123  ' as string from dual
  union all
  select 10, '12.45' as string from dual
  union all
  select 11, '12 45' as string from dual
  union all
  select 12, '12,45' as string from dual
  union all
  select 13, '-1234' as string from dual
  union all
  select 14, '+1234' as string from dual
  union all
  select 15, 'A2345' as string from dual
)
select testcase, '''' || string || '''' as string
from strings
where to_int(string) is not null
;

  TESTCASE STRING
---------- ---------------------
         1 '12345'
         2 '1234'
         3 '123'
         4 '12'
         5 '1'
         6 '01'
         8 '  345'
         9 '123  '

8 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try CAST(var AS NUMBER)?

Answer (score 0):

Also try this instead

```
select floor(to_number(TRANSLATE(' +1234.34','+-',' '))) from dual;
```

Assume +1234.34 is the input

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with a variable `foo_code`

```
IF TRIM(TRANSLATE(TRANSLATE(TRIM(foo_code), ' ', 'x'), '0123456789', ' ')) IS NULL THEN
  foo_number := TO_NUMBER(foo_code);
END IF;
```

breaking it down:

- Trim leading and trailing spaces
- Translate any internal spaces into an 'x' - think of the test case '1234 098' (i.e a simple string breaking the third condition)
- translate any digits into spaces
- Trim leading and trailing spaces
- If everything was numeric you should be left with an empty string, which in Oracle terms is NULL